# troubleshooting _mkdir failure

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010-express

```
#include <iostream>
#include <direct.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 if( _mkdir("d:\\a\\b") == 0 ){
   cout << "success";
 }    else if (  _mkdir("d:\\a") == EEXIST ) {
   cout << "Directory was not created because dirname is the name of an existing   file, directory, or device.";
      }
         else if (  _mkdir("d:\\a") == ENOENT ) {
      cout << "Path was not found.";
    }
}
```

On running the program the output is unexpected.*(Most of the times it is a fail. I don't know the reason)*

sometimes i see success.Many times i if i remove double slash `\\` with single slash `\` the message is success .
This thing is making me furious. Why is this happening ?
Are `backslashes` the problem ?

**UPDATE**

in visual c++ 2010 express edition when i press **CTRL+F5** the output is only **press any key to continue...**

Comment: When _mkdir fails try to look at the value of global variable errno, it will probably give you the reason.

Comment: No, you can't just test the return value against `EEXIST` and `ENOENT`, you have to check `errno`.

Comment: ..and that was b'coz i was trying to create both a and b with the same call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The double slashes are correct. Check [the error number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to find out why it is failing:

> Each of these functions returns the value 0 if the new directory was created. On an error the function returns –1 and sets errno as follows:
>   EEXIST - Directory was not created because dirname is the name of an existing file, directory, or device.
>   ENOENT - Path was not found.

Note that:

> _mkdir can create only one new directory per call, so only the last component of dirname can name a new directory.

Likely causes:

- you are trying to create both `a` and `b` with the same call (use e.g. [`SHCreateDirectoryEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762131%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead)
- the directory already exists

Comment: [_mkdir, _wmkdir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You've been rather vague about what *fails* means in your case. Could it be related to the fact that you are trying to create multiple folders at once?

You can only create the folder `d:\a\b` if `d:\a` already exists. Otherwise, you'll need to first create `d:\a` and then create `d:\a\b`.

[Here's the code I wrote](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/ensuring-a-path-exists) to correctly create a directory to any depth.

Answer (score 1):

Note that _mkdir doesn't return ENOENT or EEXIST, those are the values of `errno` after the call to _mkdir.  If _mkdir fails, it will always return -1 according to the documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I received this error too. In my case `_mkdir()` was actually returning `13 : EACCESS`. I can't say for sure why, but changing delimiter from '\\' to '/' actually solved my problem. According to [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/562368-mkdir-wont-do-me), behaviour of `mkdir()` is governed by the platform, and in my case I'm using `VC++2012` on Windows 7.

Update: Problem is not the delimiter. To create a folder, I recursively attempt to create  its parents while checking for `_mkdir()`'s result. To create `C:\1\2` I first attempt to create `C:` which not only already exists, but also the permission to create it, is not granted. Seems that permission to create a folder is checked before the actual check if its existing! That's why I get `EACCESS`.